# Grapics cards driver issue on unsupported macbook

Tags: bootcamp, games

tried to install Windows for gaming and had one unclear issue.

I successfully installed WINDOWS 10 on my macbook 13 mid 2010, than BOOTCAMP drivers and when I tried to play Minecraft, it showed me error with OpenGl. Than I tried to install drivers on official nvidia site and... It worked! I successfully opened minecraft but in main menu was something strange like blinking or artefacts idk when I move cursor(I think it's because of updating screen)(see on video). After I opened game - same story. Especially when I open Inventory or when I see water. Than I remembered, that I had some games on steam and tried to play "mirror's edge", but some textures and in-game littering like on dors blinked. Oh, and also in zoom desktop EVERYTHING was blinking. Impossible to study.

[image: problem]

I don't actually know what to do, if you have solution, please tell me, I will be thankful.

Comment: Were did you get the Boot Camp drivers? Did you install Windows 10 to BIOS or EFI boot?

Comment: I got drivers in BOOTCAMP ASSISTANT app on mac os and installed with BIOS boot